# Intellij automatically closes opened browsers when TestNG run is done

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, testng

I love using Intellij IDEA, however there's a problem when using it for running selenium webdriver via testNG. As soon as the run is done, I guess Intellij performs some kind of cleanup and automatically closes any browsers that were opened during the run.

I'd like to be able to keep the browsers opened, so I can see the page where the fail happened. Any ideas how to prevent that automatic cleanup?

Comment: Please check your driver version and chrome version

Answer (score 1):

Hy,
Check if you don't have a  "driver.quit(); " or something who is launch after your test failed.(maybe in a @After-Something method).

Comment: There's definitely no code that's closing the browser. It's intellij. If I run it in eclipse or by command line, the browser stays open